# Sencha Touch error: trying to create a component with an xtype that has not been registered

Tags: sencha-touch

I have an xtype form with the following item:

```
items:[{
                     xtype:'combo'
                    ,fieldLabel:'Combo 1'
                    ,store:['Item 1', 'Item 2']
                }]
```

But trying to load the page in chrome gives the error: you are trying to create a component with an xtype that has not been registered. How do I register it?

The xtype button works fine, just seems to be combo.

Thanks

**Edit:**

Here is the layout of my scripts:

```
 <head>

    <script src="lib/touch/sencha-touch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="lib/touch/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
inside this script tag is my main code, using Ext.setup({ ... }) to launch it
</script>
```

Comment: can you post your `script` tags where you're including ExtJS?

Comment: I have edited my original question to add the layout of my script tags. I also added that other xtypes such as 'button' are working as expected.

Comment: i browsed the sencha-touch.js file, and it does not provide an xtype combo ...

Comment: It seems in sencha touch the xtype to use is 'select', compared with 'combo' for the extjs framework. However, I still get the same error upon replacing 'combo' with 'select'

Comment: slightly confusing question seeing as you mention ExtJS in the question title, and no mention of Sencha Touch in the question text (only the tag)

Comment: Hi Jaitsu. I assumed that Sencha Touch used the same syntax and commands as ExtJS as they seemed so similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xtype is selectfield not combo or select

```
Ext.reg('selectfield', Ext.form.Select);
```